Microsoft WebView2: how to get the directory absolute path through 'showDirectoryPicker' in JavaScript
I want to access the absolute path of directory selected by user in WebView2, I know it is impossible in browser, but want to know if I can achieve this in WebView2

you could use showDirectoryPicker in JavaScript, but it won’t give the absolute path. i have prepared sample with the windows form which use the FolderBrowserDialog.
index.html:
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Directory Picker</title>
    <script>
        function selectDirectory() {
            // Send a message to .NET to open the folder picker
            window.chrome.webview.postMessage({
                type: 'select-directory'
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select a Directory</h1>
    <button onclick="selectDirectory()">Choose Directory</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
</body>

</html>

form1.cs:
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace WebView2DirectoryPicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeAsync();

        }
        private async void InitializeAsync()
        {
            await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
            webView21.CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived += WebView_WebMessageReceived;

            // Use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory for the path to work correctly from output directory
            string currentDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            webView21.Source = new Uri($"file:///{System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDir, "index.html")}");
        }

        private void WebView_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            var message = args.WebMessageAsJson;
            var json = JsonDocument.Parse(message);

            if (json.RootElement.GetProperty("type").GetString() == "select-directory")
            {
                // Open the Folder Browser Dialog to allow the user to select a folder
                using (var folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                {
                    folderDialog.Description = "Select a directory";
                    folderDialog.UseDescriptionForTitle = true; // Only supported on Windows Vista and later

                    if (folderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string selectedPath = folderDialog.SelectedPath;

                        // Display the selected path in a MessageBox for now
                        MessageBox.Show("Absolute Path: " + selectedPath);

                        // Optionally send the path back to JavaScript to display in the HTML page
                        webView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync($"document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Selected Path: {selectedPath}';");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}



Thank you for the detailed example, this is what i did.

OK, I found a workaround. Instead of using webview's dirctory picker, we can use native client's directory, like winform, WPF, whatever you use. Use postMessage to communicate.
